# Theory of Contraints Technical Reference

Tags: constraint, reference-request, production-planning

I have dived into [Theory of Constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constraints) by reading [*The Goal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goal_(novel)), [*It's Not Luck*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Not_Luck), [*Isn't it Obvious*](https://www.amazon.ca/Isnt-Obvious-Revised-Eliyahu-Goldratt-ebook/dp/B00408ALES), and [*Critical Chain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_Chain_(novel)). I am currently reading [*Goldratt's Rules of Flow*](https://www.amazon.ca/Goldratts-Rules-Flow-Efrat-Goldratt-Ashlag-ebook/dp/B0B9VH7TTZ).

While I enjoy these short novels, they do not serve as a concise technical reference. Is there a comprehensive reference for Theory of Constraints?